# Are 'building installer' questions off-topic at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I noticed this question was closed as off-topic: [WiX localization garbled words under installer properties tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360812/wix-localization-garbled-words-under-installer-properties-tab).

Are questions related to building installers off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Installer questions are on-topic. The close voters there may have noticed the question was about an encoding problem, not installation *per se*, but encoding problems are also on-topic. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I would have said that given building installers is a part of the development process and can be quite technical in itself, as long as the question asks a specific technical question that isn't too broad, then it's reasonable :)

Comment: "Building installer" questions aren't off-topic at all. However, this question seems to lack details necessary for it to be answered constructively. The current close-reason is wrong IMO, but it doesn't really deserve to be open in its current form either.

Comment: On second thought, the only way the question would be off-topic is if it describes a *font* issue, as those are indeed not programming-related. However, the question lacks sufficient details to be sure that's the case.

Comment: I agree - it clearly doesn't deserve to be closed as off-topic for being about installers, but it does kinda seem to deserve to be closed as "unclear what you're asking", or perhaps off-topic under the new "debugging questions need to post code" reason.

Comment: I guess I have an understanding or insight because I've used InstallShield, WiX and Inno. So it was not a leap fro me to understand what he needed.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would say that building installers **are** part of the development process and I've added my (albeit binding) vote to reopen.

I've also removed the comment about it being off topic which might mislead other users.

As a more general note it would be better if you made it clearer in the question that you were building/testing the installer and got this problem rather than just *running* the installer as an end user.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It seemed like the community was being a bit too rigid and harsh (especially the two or three downvotes).